# May be a SFINAE BUG in complier when use template?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use the standard code to write the utils like std::is_union,we know class type can not extends union type,it's error,so some code like these

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class class_type_can_extends :public T{
public:
    using type = void;
};

template<typename T,typename U = void>
struct is_not_union:std::false_type {

};

template<typename T>
struct is_not_union < T, std::void_t<typename class_type_can_extends <T>::type >> :std::true_type {

};

class c_data{

};
union u_data{
};

int main(){
 /*#1*/  std::cout<< is_not_union<c_data>::value<<std::endl; /*print true*/
 /*#2*/  std::cout<< is_not_union<u_data>::value<<std::endl; /*this code make 
         all complier error*/
}
```

g++ print error:

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘class class_type_can_extends<u_data>’:
main.cpp:26:43:   recursively required by substitution of ‘template<class T> struct is_not_union<T, std::void_t<typename class_type_can_extends<T>::type> > [with T = u_data]’
main.cpp:26:43:   required from here
main.cpp:3:7: error: base type ‘u_data’ fails to be a struct or class type
 class class_type_can_extends :public T {
```

clang print error:

```
main.cpp:3:38: error: unions cannot be base classes
class class_type_can_extends :public T {
                              ~~~~~~~^
main.cpp:14:47: note: in instantiation of template class 'class_type_can_extends<u_data>' requested here
struct is_not_union < T, std::void_t<typename class_type_can_extends <T>::type >> :std::true_type {
                                              ^
main.cpp:26:23: note: during template argument deduction for class template partial specialization 'is_not_union<T,
      std::void_t<typename class_type_can_extends<T>::type> >' [with T = u_data]
        /*#2*/  std::cout << is_not_union<u_data>::value << std::endl; /*this code make
                             ^
main.cpp:26:23: note: in instantiation of template class 'is_not_union<u_data, void>' requested here
1 error generated.
```

vs:

> error C2569

why #2 code make complier error,The complier would be using SFINAE rules on #2 code(substituted T by "u_data" ,then Failed ),and to chose primary template?why the sfinae not effective here,may be a bug here?

Comment: @Yunnosch c++14 or later

Comment: @Yunnosch #2 code makes error,but SFINAE would effective  here (class type class_type_can_extends  cannot has a base which the type is union,It's error,so the secode template substitution failed,It will use primary template),in fact,the complier report the error,the SFINAE is not effective here?

Comment: Seems my environment has trouble with `void_t`, even when using C++17. Sorry for inconveniencing you, but with a providing anactual MRE right away you could have avoided it. I was hunting for the problem in the incorrect MRE. I kept assuming an `#include` in the "missing" line 2, which provided a declaration of void_t. Now it seems it is on my side. Sorry.

Comment: Actually you changed not the code to match the error messages, you changed the error messages to match the code (but not the picture of your error messages). Either is fine. I just hope both are what you are actually seeing at home...

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for your suggestion,Now could we talk about the question,why the SFINAE rules does not effective on substuted T by "content" ，Instead，the complier report error?

Comment: @Yunnosch In other words,In my understand,It's just a substution failed,It's not error

Comment: If somebody could point out how I can make my compiler (g++ (tdm-1) 5.1.0) get along with void_t, so that I can help here, I would be happy and apologise in more detail. Until then: No, sorry. I cannot help without experimenting and I cannot experiment without getting rid of the void_t proplem. Good luck. I hope the now clean MRE will get you some substantial help, once a few more time zones have seen your question.

Comment: The first experiment I would try is by the way to listen to the compiler complaining about "neither struct nor class" and replace the `union` with `struct`.

Comment: @Yunnosch std::void_t needs c++14 or later,So you can write template<typename T> struct nonstd_void{using type = void} ,you can use like typename nonstd_void<T>::type  to instead std::void_t<T>

Comment: I did try C++14 and C++17.

Comment: @Yunnosch g++ (tdm-1) 5.1.0 is not support c++17

Comment: It says so (at least codeblocks 17.12 does allow to config that)... I admit that I am not very good with standard version hopping. Could be my fault.

Comment: Bad news, when using the void_t workaround you propose, then I can compile without more errors than you quote. But then I can compile completely without **any** errors or warnings (`-Wall -pedantic -Wextra`). So I cannot reproduce your errors in a different way now: Not having any errors.... I think we should give up here, I probably waste more of your time than I help. Or maybe try your own workaround. It could change something in an interesting way. Maybe show the code with the workaround, mabye it makes the quesiton accessable to more people (using weird compilers like me...).

Comment: When discussing the code with the proposed workaround (and assuming you still  get the errors then), my contribution boils down to "Cannot reproduce with g++ (tdm-1) 5.1.0.". (Which is of course very different from my previous "Cannot reproduce", which would be a close-vote reason.) So, we are looking at a different behaviour of compilers. One possible explanation is a bug in both of the compilers you tried.... Not exactly likely. That's all folks. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

> Only the failures in the types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type or its template parameter types or its explicit specifier (since C++20) are SFINAE errors. If the evaluation of a substituted type/expression causes a side-effect such as instantiation of some template specialization, generation of an implicitly-defined member function, etc, errors in those side-effects are treated as hard errors

SFINAE applies on immediate context, here you have a hard error failure.

In `typename class_type_can_extends<T>::type`, SFINAE applies if `type` doesn't exist, not if instantiation of `class_type_can_extends<T>` fails.

Notice that we cannot distinguish between `union` and class types using only standard C++
(without `std::is_union`). Most compilers provide intrinsics for that.

Comment: the key is that instantiation faild does not effective in SFINAE?

Comment: Added some reference: instantiation is a side effect (treated as hard error). In short, yes, instantiation failed does not effective in SFINAE.

Comment: thanks ,i have an other question by your question that is what is immediate context?

Comment: Mostly just what is directly written, so `T` and `std::void_t<typename class_type_can_extends <T>::type >` in your case (without the side effect such as instantiation).

Comment: Thanks,but an other question about your explanation is: template<typename T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>> call(){},template<typename T,typename U=void> struct test{};,template<typename T> struct test<T,std::void_t<decltype(call<T>())>>{};,when using test<float>,then during instantiating function call,the return type is error,The error happens during instantiatiation, Is it a hard error?If it is,why complier didn't report error

Comment: No, it is just an immediate error. `call<T/*=float*/>()` is well formed, but discarded of overload for SFINAE. `std::void_t<decltype(call<T/*=float*/>())>` is substitution failure too (no available overload, so no decltype). `test<float>` would use primary template and not the specialization.

Comment: what's the way   to decide what is immediate error or hard error simplely?

Comment: depends on your explanation,std::void_t<decltype(call<float>())> needs to split into two processes,One is instantiation call template function,and during this process,std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<float,int>> is just a immediate error rather than hard error,and we reback to the other process std::void_t<decltype(call<T/*=float*/>())> ,in this context ,no function call lookup for type float,so decltype failed ,it's immediate error too?So ,overall,there are immediate errors?